# Ruby if statement evaluation

Tags: ruby

I want to itterate over a array of key,value pairs from post parameters:

```
Parameters:
  {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"c6VYssp33I075nfv1ViPty38+aZSkWM/jh6oll2pYS8=", 
  "permission"=>
    {"employment_id"=>"7", 
     "organisation_level"=>"all_below", 
     "permissions"=>"view_permissions", 
     "users"=>"", 
     "organisation"=>"", 
     "functions"=>"", 
     "statistics"=>""}, 
  "commit"=>"Opslaan"}
```

I take the permission map out of these parameters and try to process it. Basically I want to check **if the key isn't employment_id and the value is present**.

```
params.each do |k,v|
  if(!(k.eql?"employment_id") && v.present?)
   p v
  end

end
```

When running the if statement in this for each I ran into some strange behaviour and **I wonder if someone can shine some light on this situation**

I ended up with this if statement, it works and evaluates like I expect it to. It only prints the values when the value is not `""` or `nil` and the key isnt `employment_id`

```
if(!(k.eql?"employment_id") && v.present?)
  p v
end
```

However, The following 2 if statements dont work as I expect. Both print all values. They evaluate to `true` while I think they shouldn't.

```
if(!k.eql?"employment_id" && v.present?)
  p v 
end
```

and

```
if !k.eql?"employment_id" && v.present?
  p v 
end
```

Comment: Looks like its a precedence thing - check out http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of your confusion is the priority of operations, especially in thew face of you omitting parenthesis. In your case, the statements are evaluated as follows:

```
if(!k.eql?"employment_id" && v.present?)
# equivalent to 
if (!(k.eql?("employment_id" && v.present?)))

if !k.eql?"employment_id" && v.present?
# equivalent to 
if !k.eql?("employment_id" && v.present?)
```

And here, `"employment_id" && v.present?` evaluates to `true`. So essentially, you are asking `!k.eql?(true)` which, with `k` being a string always evaluates to `true` (because of the negation).

To circumvent the issue, make sure to use parenthesis appropriately. Preferrably you should use them for method calls like so

```
k.eql?("employment_id")
```

instead of like

```
(k.eql? "employment_id")
```

That way, you make it clear what the method arguments are and avoid ambiguities which are then needed to be resolved by precedence. I personally tend to only omit method parenthesis if it is really clear what the arguments are. Especially in more complex statements like yours, it just doesn't make much sense to omit them and thus reduce clarity.

Comment: And as a side comment, you could simplify your statement to `k != "employment_id" && v.present?`

Comment: if I evaluate `"employment_id" && "".present?` however in my ruby console it yields `false`

Comment: Method calls have higher precedence than anything else and direct comparison has higher precedence than `&&`. So my example above is equivalent to `(k != "employment_id") && (v.present?)`. In your example, `"employment_id"` is truethy, `"".present?` is falsey. So the result would be `false`. See the link by @redspike above for more information about operator precedence in ruby.